# Horizontal scrolling of a row in a grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to horizontally scroll a row, that should occupy 100% of the width of the page, without it overflowing out of the background image and also keeping the header text in focus.

What I tried:

- Applying overflow to `grid`. Using overflow on `grid` will contain grid items in an invisible box and forces it to be centered, ignoring the `flex-start` direction i want. Also, scrolling through the grid items will hide the previous items out of focus.
- Applying overflow to `Box`. The `Box` tag is a wrapper for the whole page and while applying `overflow` allows the row to be scrolled through without the grid items being contained and centered, the header text isn't kept in focus and scrolling through the items will cause the header text to be out of focus.

Is there any to achieve a scrollable row that also keeps header text in focus?

Thanks!

Code:

```
const pages = [
  {
    name: "one",
    route: "oneR",
    image: oneImage,
  },
  {
    name: "two",
    route: "twoR",
    image: twoImage,
  },{
    name: "three",
    route: "threeR",
    image: threeImage,
  },{
    name: "four",
    route: "fourR",
    image: fourImage,
  },{
    name: "five",
    route: "fiveR",
    image: fiveImage,
  },{
    name: "six",
    route: "sixR",
    image: sixImage,
  },
  
];

export const Home = (props) => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState('Option 1');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setOption(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={homeTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />

      <Box
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        minHeight="100vh"
        sx={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        }}
      >
        <Container>
          <Typography variant="h2" component="h2" paddingTop={6}>
            TEST HEADER
          </Typography>

          <Select
    labelId="Selectoptions"
    disableUnderline
    variant="standard"
    defaultValue={option}
    value={option}
    onChange={handleChange}
    IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
    MenuProps={{
      
      sx:{
        '.MuiMenu-paper' : {
          outline:'solid 4px',
          marginTop:"4px",
        outlineColor:"white",
          backgroundColor:'black',
          width:"32%",
          borderRadius:"0px"
        }
      }
    }}
    sx={{backgroundColor:"transparent", width:"35%", height:"6vh", outlineColor:"white", outlineStyle:"solid", outlineWidth:"3px", marginTop:"1%",
    '.MuiSelect-iconStandard' : {
      marginRight:'2%',
      stroke:"white",
      strokeWidth:'2px'
    }
  }}>
    <MenuItem value={"Option 1"} disableRipple><Typography variant="h5" sx={{marginTop:'5px'}}>Option 1</Typography></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"Option 2"} disableRipple><Typography variant="h5" sx={{marginTop:'5px'}}>Option 2</Typography></MenuItem>

  </Select>
  {option === "Option 1" && (
    <div sx={{maxWidth:"100%"}}>
          <Grid
            container
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
            direction="row"
            wrap="nowrap"
            spacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 3 }}
            sx={{ paddingTop: "4%", paddingLeft:"110%", paddingBottom: "2%",}}
          >
            {pages.map((page, index) => (
              <Grid item xs="auto" sm="auto" md="auto" key={index}>
                <OverlayPreview
                  name={page.name}
                  route={page.route}
                  image={page.image}
                />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
          </div>
  )}
  {option === 'Option 2' && (
          <Grid
            container
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
            spacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 3 }}
            sx={{ paddingTop: "2%", paddingBottom: "2%" }}
          >
            <Grid item xs={10} sm={5} md={3}>
              <OverlayPreview
                name={"Option"}
                href={"https://www.google.com"}
                image={cImage}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          )}
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue by wrapping the header text and footer in a `Box` tag so that applying overflow to the `grid` tag will keep the header and footer in viewport when user scrolls through the items.